# SQL: "Conditional" when creating a domain

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

How can I define or change a domain based on another attribute value? F.e. the domain for salary is a numeric value > 500. But if a date the person was hired > January 1st, 2013, then the salary must be > 1000.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: A check constraint referencing both columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table emp (
  empno number,
  hire_date date,
  salary number,
  constraint ck_hire_salary check ( (hire_date > date '2013-01-01' and salary > 1000) or 
                                    (salary > 500) );
```

Admittedly this is Oracle syntax because I don't use psql too often anymore, but this should essentially work.

No no no on using a trigger for such a thing.

And only (a single) no, using a check constraint for such a thing. This is business logic not data integrity logic, so using a check constraint is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you. 
I found another way: ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CHECK (...);

Answer (score 0):

No. A domain defines a fixed subset of values in a type. It makes no more sense to speak of dependencies on a salary domain than on numeric. They are their own thing and not connected to a table.

You can, of course, set a trigger on a table to enforce business rules like this.

In theory, you could create your own type combining (salary,employment_date) but since they are (presumably) unrelated that strikes me as a pretty poor idea.

Comment: I haven't used triggers yet. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: The manuals cover plpgsql and triggers in some detail. All you basically want to do is check your values and RAISE an exception if there is a problem.

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not what I really want to do. The values for salary less than 1000 should not appear in the table, if the date of hiring is greater than January 1st.

Comment: So do what I said. Write a trigger and raise an exception if someone tries to insert/update a row such that it breaks your rule.

Comment: The data will be biased, if we do so, as the salary must be greater than 1000, not equal to 1000. How do I know, which salary is a correct one for a particular person when updating it?